# Hint solving an integral

Tags: calculus

I want a hint for the following integral:
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^{2}\sqrt{1- a^{2}+x^{2}}}$$
where $a$ is a real constant.

In fact, 
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^{2}\sqrt{1- a^{2}+x^{2}}} = -\frac{\sqrt{1- a^{2}+x^{2}}}{x(1- a^{2})}$$
why?